# How to reload/refresh subgrid in JQgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, reload, subgrid

This is my all of my subgrid code in jquery. My problem is , that I have a dropdown with user. Each user have their own id , transmitted by GET method. When I select a different user I expected to show in the subgrid different values, but it not happens just after i manually refresh the page (crtl + f5). Im using ajax also and json . 
This is my code :

```
subGrid : true, 
        subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
          //var projectIdRow = $('#list2').jqGrid('getCell',rowId,'projectid');
          //alert(row_id);
          var subgrid_table_id;
          subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
          $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"'></table>");
          $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            url:"/taskuri/subGrid/?id="+row_id+"&userid="+userAlocat,
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ['SubTask',' ','Pri','Responsabil','Alocator','Alocat','Deadline','Estimat','Lucrat',' '],
            colModel: [ 
              {name:"SubTask",index:"SubTask",width:'770%',align:"left",sortable:false},
              {name:'finished',index:'finished', width:'42%',sortable:false},
              {name:"Pri",index:"Pri",width:'60%', sortable:true},
              {name:"Responsabil",index:"Responsabil",width:'144%',sortable:false},
              {name:"Alocator",index:"Alocator",width:'140%',sortable:false},
              {name:"Alocat",index:"Alocat",width:'122%',sortable:false},
              {name:"Deadline",index:"Deadline",width:'122%',sortable:false},
              {name:"Estimat",index:"Estimat",width:'84%',align:"right",sortable:false},
              {name:"Lucrat",index:"Lucrat",width:'94%',align:"right"},
              {name:"Delete",index:"Delete",width:'48%',align:"right"},
            ],
            height: '100%',
            rowNum:20
            });

         var useridLogat = $("#userid").val();
        },
        gridComplete: function(){ //afiseaza subgridurile by default
               var grid = $("#list2");
               var svi_id = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
               $.each(svi_id, function (index, rowId) {
                    $.post('/taskuri/checkSubtask/', { rowId: rowId}, function(data){
                        if (data >= 1){ //data reprezinta numarul row urilor din query
                            grid.jqGrid('expandSubGridRow',rowId);
                        }else{
                            // else ul face , ca userul sa numai dea click pe poza +, asa se evita sa afiseze headurl ala fara date, adica cand nu contine date subgridul
                            $('.sgcollapsed a').remove();  
                            $(".ui-sgcollapsed:eq("+index+")" ).removeClass("sgcollapsed");
                        }
                    });
               });
        },
```

What can I do? Thx

Comment: Yeah I know its friday afternoon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  //if this textbox
     $("#textinputID").keyup(function() { 
      reloadJQGrid();
    }); 


   //if this dropdown
    $("#dropdownID").on("change",function() {
        reloadJQGrid();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this     

    function reloadJQGrid(){

            jQuery.ajax({ 
               type: "post", 
               url: ${contextPath}"/webappName/methodName",
               cache: false, 
               data:$("#testForm").serialize(), 
               success: function(response)
               { 
                 jQuery("#Testgrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
                },
               error: function(){ 
                   alert();
                   alert('server errors..');
                   }
               });
            } 

    //if this textbox
     $("#textinputID").keyup(function() { 
      reloadJQGrid();
    }); 

   //if this dropdown
    $("#dropdownID").on("change",function() {
        reloadJQGrid();

    });
```

Comment: and after when i select an item from dropdown I always reload the entire jqgrid.